# How to pass personalization into a cloud page URL that has web to lead code

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, web2lead

Use case: I have this CloudPage - https://us.abc.com/signupform and it is populated with web2lead code from Sales cloud so upon submission a lead record is created directly in Sales Cloud.

This sign up form is hosted on multiple places like on Facebook, LinkedIn etc. Currently, I'm creating multiple cloud pages like https://us.abc.com/signupform_facebook and https://us.abc.com/signupform_linkedin and passing the hidden value in the form to track the number of leads generated by each channel. Is there any a way in the Marketing Cloud that I construct the URL to pass the hidden value so I'm not creating multiple cloudpages for same CTA? Something like below?

https://us.abc.com/signupform?channel=%%mchannel%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. If you need to encrypt the data passed to the landing page, use the [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function. Alternatively, if you just ned to include non-sensitive information in the URL, like your mcchannel variable, but simply add it to the query string in your content:

**CloudPagesURL**

```
<!--%%[
SET @CloudPageID = 1234
SET @mcchannel = "facebook"
]%%-->
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(@CloudPageID,'mcchannel',@mcchannel)=%%" alias="Web To Lead">Click Me</a>
```

**Unencrypted Params**

```
<!--%%[
SET @mcchannel = "facebook"
]%%-->
<a href="http://cloud.my.sapdomain.com/mylandingpage?mcchannel=%%=v(@mcchannel)=%%" alias="Web To Lead">Click Me</a>
```

Then to get hold of the value of the mcchannel parameter in your landing page and add it as a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="mcchannel" name="mcchannel" value="%%=RequestParameter('mcchannel')=%%">
```

Comment: This really helped! So, I passed the parameter in the URL - https://us.abc.com/signupform?mcchannel=facebook and updated my cloudpage to capture the value using RequestParameter like you said. Taking that value, I build a logic to dynamically assign the campaign in CRM. Thank you Macca!